# Summing names with same values

Tags: google-sheets

I have an spreadsheet with one column with a bunch of names ( with duplicates) and a testing column which will be either 'ok', 'not - ok' or '' (if not started). I wanted to create a formula that would get all the unique names and then count how many 'not - ok' + '' that corresponds to that name so eg

```
Column A     Column B
Bob            ok
John           not - ok
Rob            
Bob            not - ok
John           ok
Joe            ok
John
```

And the desired output would be

```
Column C    Column D
Bob           1
John          2
Rob           1
Joe           0
```

I was able to get the unique name with 
=UNIQUE(A2:A10) but not sure how to generate column D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query gives everyone with 'ok' matched in column B:

```
=query(A2:B, "select A, count(B) where B matches '.*ok' group by A", 0)
```

---

if you like to make custom headers in this query, use this formula:

```
=query(A2:B, 
"select A, count(B) where B matches '.*ok' group by A label A 'name1', count(B) 'name2'",
0)
```

Comment: Seems like a 'count' is showing up. Is there a way i can give a custom header to Column C and Column D?

Comment: To make custom header add at the end of query this text:  label A 'name1', count(B) 'name2'

Comment: Could you update your answer with that? I think I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
=query(A2:B, "select A, count(B) where A <> '' and B <> 'ok' group by A", 0)
```

or

```
=query(A2:B, "select A, count(B) where A <> '' and (B = '' or B = 'not - ok') group by A", 0)
```

Comment: Awesome if I wanted to put a regex eg '*ok' is there a way to achieve that? I just noticed that some of the spreadsheets has the name 'Bob - ok'

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `pivot`. "Names" goes in rows, as value you can use count of "column B" elements. Then add a global filter for the "ok" status